# Trying to print unicode characters to the console using string.format()

Tags: python, unicode, string-formatting, unicode-string

below is the snippet in question:

```
print '{:─^10}'.format('') # Print '─' character 10 times
```

I'm using this to create nice console borders and such. The problem is, running this in my py file with ***# coding UTF-8*** gives me: **ValueError: Invalid conversion specification**

If I run this same script in the python shell, it spits out the escaped characters: **'\xc4\xc4\xc4\x...'**

I don't know how (in my script) to get this to print out the **'─'** character. It can print the **'─'** character just fine if I use **print '─'** because of the UTF-8 encoding, but for some reason it won't allow it in the **string.format()** function.

Any suggestions? I'm sure this is probably easy to fix, but i'm VERY new to python programming.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Python2, you need to use unicode (`u''`) strings:

```
print u'{:─^10}'.format(u'')
```

Comment: **wow** I can't believe I missed that. I tried the u in front of the '{:─^10}' but I didn't think to put it within the format argument. Thanks so much! I knew this was going to be simple lol